# dart - toList() causes the casting exception

Tags: dart, mongo-dart

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB from my code using `mongo_dart` package.

So my approach is below,

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

class MongoDB {
  late Db db;

  MongoDB(
      {hosts = const ['myserver1', 'myserver2', 'myserver3'],
      port = '27017',
      username = 'admin',
      password = 'mypassword',
      dbname = 'mydb',
      authSource = 'admin'}) {
    db = Db.pool(
        hosts.map((elem) => "mongodb://$username:$password@$elem:$port/$dbname?authSource=$authSource").toList());
  }
```

When executing this code an exception occurs which has the message `Expected a value of type 'List<String>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'` on `.toList()`.

All the parameters are string types, but why does it happen?

Comment: Why are you constructing a Uri with string concatenation instead of using parameters to a Uri constructor?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I didn't know that.. I just followed the example `mongo_dart` provided, and they used string to construct uri. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that i am not an expert on Dart's type inference, but this is probably what is happening:

The `host` argument for your `MongoDB` constructor omits specific type information, which does not give the analyzer enough information to infer that you *always* want a `List<String>`. So it assumes it to be `dynamic`

There are multiple way to fix this:

1. Specify the type in the arguments of the constructor: `MongoDB({List<String> hosts = const ['myserver1', 'myserver2', 'myserver3'], ...})`
2. Specify that your `map` will always return a `String` and thus `toList()` will produce a `List<String>`: `hosts.map<String>((elem) => "mongodb://$username:$password@$elem:$port/$dbname?authSource=$authSource").toList()`

Comment: when I stopped before executing `DB.pool(...)` on debug mode and look `hosts.runtimeType` up, it was `List<String>`. So I thought there is no need to specify the type in `MongoDB` constructor, like the first way you answered... well, both way you gave work well, thank you!

Comment: The compiler actually assumes `hosts` has type `dynamic`. That's why `hosts.map((elem) => "some string")` does *not* get inferred as `hosts.map<String>(elem) => "some string")`, like it would if the compiler knew that `hosts` was even an iterable. It doesn't, it's a completely dynamic invocation of "something called `map`" on "something". The dynamic invocation omits the type argument to `map` (since it was not inferred), and therefore it becomes `dynamic`, and the call creates a `List<dynamic>` at runtime. Containing only strings, but we're long past type inference, so nobody knows that.

Comment: @lrn Thanks. I've updated my answer to change it to `dynamic` instead of `List<dynamic>`